# How to get json from rapidminer web service to laravel?

Tags: json, laravel, rapidminer

i try to connect rapidminer web service () to laravel, but it doesnt connect properly and show different from i want. please help, thanks

```
$client = Http::get('http://desktop-qo1l6ph:8080/api/rest/process/procTrain?nim=1011381419228',

['auth' => ['admin','94k0z4007']]);

dd($client);
```

and this is the
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glnzL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel only gives you a wrapper object not the `GuzzleHttp\Client` directly.

Either use the Laravel API:

```
Http::withBasicAuth('admin', '94k0z4007')->get('http://desktop-qo1l6ph:8080/api/rest/process/procTrain?nim=1011381419228')
```

or create a `new GuzzleHttp\Client()`